# In angular why are class and comment directives not bound?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XBJjr6uR1rMAg3Ng7DiJ?p=preview

I would expect these two to look the same:

```
<span dt-attrib="{{person.name}}">This won't be here</span><br/>
<span class="dt-class: {{person.name}};">This won't be here.</span> - this does not process
```

But this is what I get:

```
This text was set by the dtAttrib directive, value="Burt Finklestein"
This text was set by the dtClass directive, value="{{person.name}}"
```

Code:

```
app.directive("dtAttrib", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.text('This text was set by the dtAttrib directive' + DisplayValueString(attrs.dtAttrib));
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive("dtClass", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.text('This text was set by the dtClass directive' + DisplayValueString(attrs.dtClass));
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you hit the nail on the head in your own plunker with the line `<span class="dt-class-b: person.name;">This won't be here.</span> - this DOES process, with no curly braces`. Class directives take the form C - Class: `<div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>` (see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) which means that the directive is passed to the parser and bound from there not during the brace parsing phase.

The reason your seeing it process in the attribute case is that the pre-processor (angular core directive compilers) doesn't know to skip the attribute you created so it still processes it then sends the value as an expression which will just return.